# Hazelcast - detect false sharing

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a 3 node Hazelcast cluster which has quite a bit of concurrent activity. As load has increased, I've been noticing periodic slow performance when interacting with items in the cluster. For example, reading from a map normally takes milliseconds but in other cases it takes 10+ seconds. This is not isolated to a single collection but happening across many different collections in the cluster. These delays are seemingly random with no obvious patterns as to when they will occur.

I've also noticed some slow operation warnings in the diagnostic logs from a map that I use to store some potentially large objects. Based on these observations, my suspicion is that I am encountering "false sharing" as described in the documentation (https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.1/manual/html-single/index.html)

> False sharing of the partition - two completely independent data structures share the same partition. For example, if there is a map employees and a map orders, the method employees.get("peter") running on partition 25 may be blocked by the method orders.get(1234) also running on partition 25. If independent data structures share the same partition, a slow operation on one data structure can slow down the other data structures.
>
> False sharing of the partition-aware operation thread - each operation thread is responsible for executing operations on a number of partitions. For example, thread 1 could be responsible for partitions 0, 10, 20, etc. and thread-2 could be responsible for partitions 1, 11, 21, etc. If an operation for partition 1 takes a lot of time, it blocks the execution of an operation for partition 11 because both of them are mapped to the same operation thread.

My first thought is that I need to find a way to reduce the size of the objects in the map which is warning about the slow operations but before proceeding with that potentially large refactor, I'd like to confirm whether or not "false sharing" is in fact the root cause. Is there any way to detect when this is happening? For example, is there any logging or JMX metrics which show how many operations are queued up for a single partition or for a single operation thread?

Comment: Did you check GC logs? Sounds like you are running into gc pauses.

Comment: Yes, I've reviewed some GC metrics and there doesn't seem to be any significant stop the world events so I don't believe GC is the issue.

Comment: You should be able to see this info in the diagnostics logs actually. If you can share the logs & member configs, I can check them.

Comment: I'd prefer not to share the exact logs as they are from a production environment. Could you let me know what I should look for in the logs?

Comment: Blocking in partition threads are the strongest candidate for 10+ secs for get operations. is there a constant slowness or intermittent blocking? Do you use EntrProcessor, MapStore or any other custom code written by you? If you have a slow running custom code which would block partition threads, that could explain 10+ secs. Do you see any interesting Hazelcast log other than TCP/IP connection events? Any slow operation logs?

Comment: Diagnostics logs do not print actual data but cluster information such as number of slow operations, GC stats, memory usage etc. Sharing diagnostics should be safe.